# Lagrange multipliers and uncommon question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose you have $n$ cobblestone blocks of dimensions $a, b$, and $c$ to build a water tank.

(a) What is the tank shape that maximizes volume? Cube, cylinder ...

(b) Determine an expression for this volume.

The exercises I have come across to this day have always said the shape of the object for volume optimization. How do I follow the reverse path? Should I list the format possibilities?

Comment: What do you mean "maximizes the volume"? Do you mean "minimize the volume for $n$ blocks? Or equivalent, maximizes the number $n$? Otherwise, just take a sphere with the radius of the Universe :)

Comment: I think it means to maximise the volume inside a tank the stones form.